# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why is the only use of the word antichrist (G500) in 1st and 2nd John?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15743/why-is-the-only-use-of-the-word-antichrist-g500-in-1st-and-2nd-john)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does the Greek word κύριος mean in 1 Cor. 12:3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16798/what-does-the-greek-word-%ce%ba%cf%8d%cf%81%ce%b9%ce%bf%cf%82-mean-in-1-cor-123)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Did Moses write Psalm 90?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16853/did-moses-write-psalm-90)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does the phrase "ἐγὼ ἐν τῷ πατρὶ καὶ ὁ πατὴρ ἐν ἐμοί ἐστιν” mean in John 10:38 as well as John 14:10?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15751/what-does-the-phrase-%e1%bc%90%ce%b3%e1%bd%bc-%e1%bc%90%ce%bd-%cf%84%e1%bf%b7-%cf%80%ce%b1%cf%84%cf%81%e1%bd%b6-%ce%ba%ce%b1%e1%bd%b6-%e1%bd%81-%cf%80%ce%b1%cf%84%e1%bd%b4%cf%81-%e1%bc%90%ce%bd-%e1%bc%90%ce%bc%ce%bf%ce%af-%e1%bc%90%cf%83%cf%84%ce%b9%ce%bd-mean-in-john-10)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is this translation of Genesis 1:1 accurate?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16809/is-this-translation-of-genesis-11-accurate)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [What is Jesus' purpose in asking about Psalm 110?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/what-is-jesus-purpose-in-asking-about-psalm-110)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [John 16:12 - What were the "many things"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/john-1612-what-were-the-many-things)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What is "that day" in John 14:20?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15632/what-is-that-day-in-john-1420)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Shema and Psalms 110: Is Mark making a case for Jesus' divinity?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/shema-and-psalms-110-is-mark-making-a-case-for-jesus-divinity)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [In Colossians 1:27, what is the meaning of “this mystery among the Gentiles, which is Christ in you, the hope of glory”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/16857/col-127-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-mystery-among-the-gentiles-which-is-chr)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

Comment: Hey community (and I don't mean you Community♦) I'm not sure you guys caught the point of this drill. Votes for the site evaluation are different than what you might give otherwise. This evaluation was supposed to suggest how useful this site is in finding the right information by comparing it to other sites that come up in searches. There are a large number of "Excellent" votes on questions here that have nothing but sucky answers. (e.g. A highest scored answer of -5 does not count as the post being an excellent resource! Even if its a good question and _someday_ may have a good answer.)

Comment: See also, [Self-evaluation: How are we doing?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/383/3555) for an explanation of the factors that these evals are meant to capture, complete with a [nifty chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png) that gives guidelines about decision making.